# Tabulated Emission Lines beyond NIST

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

It appears that when it comes to atomic lines, the most complete table is provided by the NIST website, which is, verbatim, based on the tables of *Basic Atomic Spectroscopic Data Handbook* authored by Sansonetti, of which are based on various sources.  The NIST tables are limited to neutral (I) and singly ionized (II) atoms, and I was wondering where one might be able to find lines for atoms of higher ionizations than one, or are we left to scavenge individual papers, of which many could be isolated experiments each of which detect maybe only a handful of these lines?

Alternatively, one could compute the wavelengths of the hypothetically any atom using theoretical models - or perhaps theorists have already done it and tabulated their results.  Is there such a database?

Comment: You can find papers like http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/35/6/009/pdf; maybe you could start a tabulation project!

Comment: You could obtain the MCHF code at https://nlte.nist.gov/MCHF/ and run it yourself.